# Outlook add-in does not work in certain execution environments

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm having a problem with my product.
Does anyone know the cause?
And please tell me the solution to this problem.

Execution environment
　Outlook2019 build Ver 2203(15028.20204)
　※Works correctly in other execution environments.

It always occurs when you follow the steps below.

1)Launch Outlook 2019.

2)Compose an email.

3)Click the "send" button.

4)An error occurs.

I tried debugging.
I Confirmed that there was a problem with the "localStorage.getItem()"API part in the source code.
I'm expecting the value to be returned, but I've confirmed that it's returned as "null".
This issue only occurs in dialogs opened with "displayDialogAsync"

What may be the cause?

[Office365 release notes]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/OfficeUpdates/update-history-office-2019#retail-versions-of-office-2016-c2r-and-office-2019

[display dialog async API]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

[localStorage API]

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What is the exact code? Do you have any problems on other platforms?

Comment: Dear Eugene - Sorry for the slow response.

Comment: The problem is happening only Outlook2019. but Curiously, the problem no longer occurs. 
See how it goes for a while. thank you.